# How to create multiple code behind file for .aspx page

Tags: asp.net, c#-4.0, code-behind

I have a situation where I need to create multiple code behind files for a single .aspx page in c# asp.net. Actually I have a web form on that huge coding is done and I need multiple developer's working on it simultaneously. How can I achieve the same?

Here is the code snippet I tried

Class 1 MyPartialClass.cs

```
namespace WebApplication1
{
    public partial class Default : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        protected void PrintText(string pt)
        {
            Response.Write(pt);
            //lblTest.Text = pt;    //Can not access this label in partial class.
        }
    }
}
```

Class 2 which is Default.aspx.cs

```
namespace WebApplication1
{
    public partial class Default : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            PrintText("Hello World");
        }
    }
}
```

and my HTML source

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="false" CodeBehind="Default.aspx.cs" Inherits="WebApplication1.Default" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
        <asp:Label ID="lblTest" runat="server"></asp:Label>
    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: It seem that your page needs a huge refactoring.. Are you implementing domain logic in code behind pages? If so, maybe is time to move it to a domain model.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

ASP.NET will always generate your code behind files as partial classes

```
namespace WebApplication1
{
    public partial class Default : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }
    }
}
```

You can therefor separate the code behind in different files, if you pertain the definition as `partial` and keep the class under the same namespace.

**Edit :** The Web Project

```
//Default.aspx
<%@ Page Title="Home Page" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Site.master"     AutoEventWireup="true"
    CodeBehind="Default.aspx.cs" Inherits="WebApplication1.Default" %>

<asp:Content ID="HeaderContent" runat="server" ContentPlaceHolderID="HeadContent">
</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ID="BodyContent" runat="server" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent">
    <asp:Label ID="lblTest" runat="server" Text="Label"></asp:Label>
</asp:Content>

//Default.aspx.cs
namespace WebApplication1
{
    public partial class Default : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            PrintText("Hello World");
        }
    }
}

//MyPartialClass.cs
namespace WebApplication1
{
    public partial class Default
    {
        protected void PrintText(string pt)
        {
            Response.Write(pt);
            lblTest.Text = pt;    //lblTest is accessible here
        }
    }
}
```

I haven't modified any other generated files. One thing I like to mention is that the `Default.aspx.cs` file that has been generated was generated with the class name "_Default". I have changed it to `Default` and Visual Studio refactored the change across all files that contain a definition for that class, except the `Default.aspx` file, where I had to manually modifiy from `Inherits="WebApplication1._Default"` to `Inherits="WebApplication1.Default"`.

**Edit 2:**

I kept searching the internet, and according to http://codeverge.com/asp.net.web-forms/partial-classes-for-code-behind/371053, what you are trying to do is impossible. Same idea is detailed at http://codeverge.com/asp.net.web-forms/using-partial-classes-to-have-multiple-code/377575 
If possible, consider converting from Web Site to Web Application, which supports what you are trying to achieve. Here is a walkthrough on how to perform this conversion: [http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/aa983476(v=vs.100).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/aa983476%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)

Comment: I have tried but it does not work please check question for code snippet

Comment: @AdeshArote You only need to inherit from `System.Web.UI.Page` once. Does this fix your problem?

Comment: Thank you @Alex for your reply, I have tried the same but its not working. My scenario is like I have to maintain my code behind of .aspx page in 2 different files. Right now I have created 2 partial classes 1 is under MyPartialClass.cs and another one is Default.aspx.cs

Comment: @AdeshArote I have created a small Web project similar to yours, and it works. I'll edit the answer with the contents.

Comment: I tried this in project type "web application" and it works perfect.My project type is "website", can you help me how to make this work in a website project

Comment: @AdeshArote I can not seem to make it work either. Why do you need to have a Web Site project and not a Web Application one?

Comment: I need to implement this in an existing project and that project is type of "WebSite".

Answer (score 3):

You need to set up a source safe server in order to that, like Team Foundation Server.

Comment: Exactly. And you can sign up for free for up to 5 users.... http://tfs.visualstudio.com

Answer (score 1):

You can easily just add partial classes to your code.

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/709273/Partial-Classes-in-Csharp-With-Real-Example