# Splitting up WebMethods into multiple files

Tags: c#, asp.net

I previously had a single `.aspx.cs` file that contained numerous `WebMethods`. It looked something like this:

```
// webmethods.aspx.cs

public partial class Default : System.Web.UI.Page {
    [System.Web.Services.WebMethod]
    public static string Method1() {
    }

    [System.Web.Services.WebMethod]
    public static string Method2() {
    }

    [System.Web.Services.WebMethod]
    public static string Method3() {
    }
}
```

And the corresponding `.aspx` file, that looked something like this:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" MasterPageFile="Navigation.master" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="webmethods.aspx.cs" Inherits="Default" Debug="true" %>
```

I was able to then call my WebMethods successfully using AJAX.

But the `webmethods.aspx.cs` file was getting very large, and I wanted to split the WebMethods up into different files. So I did that like this:

**webmethods.aspx.cs**:

```
// first file

namespace Foo {
    public partial class Default : System.Web.UI.Page {
        [System.Web.Services.WebMethod]
        public static string Method1() {
        }
}
```

**webmethods2.aspx.cs**:

```
// second file

namespace Foo {
    public partial class Default : System.Web.UI.Page {
        [System.Web.Services.WebMethod]
        public static string Method2() {
        }
}
```

**webmethods3.aspx**:

```
// third file

namespace Foo {
    public partial class Default : System.Web.UI.Page {
        [System.Web.Services.WebMethod]
        public static string Method3() {
        }
}
```

And changed the page directive to `Inherits="Foo.Default"`.

But now, every time I try to access any of the WebMethods in the other files via AJAX, I get an `Unknown WebMethod` error. The AJAX request is still being sent to the `webmethods.aspx.cs` file.

Can someone help guide me as to what I did wrong?

Comment: `CodeFile="webmethods.aspx.cs"` what did you change this to?

Comment: @ChetanRanpariya I didn't change it. Do I need to set the CodeFile to something else? Sorry, I come from a Python/Django background. I'm still figuring things out with ASP.NET.

Comment: What you are looking for is having multiple code behind files for single aspx page. Looks like that is not possible. Refer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23996069/how-to-create-multiple-code-behind-file-for-aspx-page Read the EDIT 2 of the answer.

Comment: I would question why you'd want to transition to an arguably stale framework?  I've seen no indication from Microsoft that there will be any new features or updates to Webforms in the future.  Writing new software with it would be ill advised.

Comment: @ErikPhilips I agree completely, but I have no say in the choice of framework for this project. The client is adamant despite my attempts at persuading them otherwise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

WebForm compilation model allows single `CodeBehind` file for a `partial class` which compiles into a single .dll. All files in `App_code` folder also compile in a single file *before* compilation of `.aspx` and `.aspx.cs`. So workaround may look like this.

```
//Default.aspx
<!DOCTYPE html>
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" Inherits="SomeApp.MyPage" %>
<%-- No CodeBehind. inherits external class--%>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <div>
            <asp:Label runat="server" ID="lblTest"></asp:Label><br />
            <asp:Button runat="server" ID="btnTest" Text="click me" OnClick="btnTest_Click" />
        </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>

//App_Code\MyPage.cs
namespace SomeApp
{
    public partial class MyPage : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        //You need to declare all page controls referred by code here
        public System.Web.UI.WebControls.Label lblTest { get; set; }

        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (!Page.IsPostBack)
            {
                lblTest.Text = "hello world from app_code";
            }
        }
    }
}

//App_code\AnotherFile.cs
namespace SomeApp
{
    public partial class MyPage : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        protected void btnTest_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
                lblTest.Text = "hello world from btnTest_Click";

        }
    }
}
```

It should work with `[WebMethod]`s as well.

Comment: Perfect! Thank you!