# Access a method which fills a gridview with a button click from a different code-behind page

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I'm trying to bind/fill a GridView.  The GridView is the only thing on that page.  No editing or anything, just a list of data.  The event that triggers the GridView fill method is on a different page.  The call to the method seems to work but when it gets to the GridView it complains that I need to reference an instance of the object.

I've tried at least a dozen approaches.  This should be simple.  I'm currently doing different variations on FindControl.

Here is the C# code that is failing:

Default.aspx.cs

```
        public class ImportCSV : System.Web.UI.Page
        {
            public ImportCSV()
            {

            // A bunch of code that is working.

                GridView LoadedDrivers = (GridView)Page.FindControl("LoadedDrivers");

                LoadedDrivers.DataSource = csvDataTable; //This is where it errors
                        LoadedDrivers.DataBind();

            )
```

Here is the code that triggers it:
Control.aspx.cs

```
namespace ControlPanelLab
{
    public partial class Control : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        //Working code

        public void LoadDriversDriversButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            //_Default.ImportCSV();
            _Default.ImportCSV importCSV = new _Default.ImportCSV();
        }
```

And the GridView that needs to be filled:

Default.aspx

```
<%@ Page Title="Driver Table" Language="C#"  AutoEventWireup="true" MasterPageFile="~/Site.Master" CodeBehind="Default.aspx.cs" Inherits="ControlPanelLab._Default" %>

    <asp:Content ID="BodyContent" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" runat="server">

    <asp:GridView ID="LoadedDrivers" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="true"></asp:GridView>

</asp:Content>
```

I've tried every combination I can think of and this at least compiles without an error.  It just blows up when I run it complaining about referencing an instance of the LoadedDrivers GridView.  I tried to put all the logic in a separate class file but I couldn't get that to work.  The ImportCSV method was originally in a button handler that worked but I had to relocate the button that triggers the event to a different page.  I tried to trigger that button with a button event sent by the new control page.

What am I missing?  Thank you for any help.

- Update -
  I should point out that the only thing happening on the Control page is the button that triggers the method which loads, parses and ultimately needs to repopulate the GridView.

The button event on the Control page does in fact start the process just fine.  All of the other activity is occurring on the Default page.  And the only thing that is not working is the GridView which exists on the Default page is not binding.

I do understand that I do not understand inheritance all that well.  That is why I am looking for guidance.

I have read many posts about triggering button clicks with JS as well as many posts about referencing precompiled classes.

The reference that I show in my code does not work, I get that.  That's why I'm asking.  Logically, there needs to be a way to trigger an event from a location that is not explicitly on the same page as the element being triggered.  It's all under the same site, indeed, shares a namespace.

How do I properly address it?

Edit to include full ImportCSV method:

```
            public ImportCSV()
            {
                //Static path to csv file
                string csvPath = ("C:/Data/drivers.csv");

                //Create a DataTable.
                DataTable csvDataTable = new DataTable();
                csvDataTable.Columns.AddRange(new DataColumn[4] { new DataColumn("id", typeof(int)),
        new DataColumn("fName", typeof(string)),
        new DataColumn("lName", typeof(string)),
        new DataColumn("Country",typeof(string)) });

                //Read the contents of CSV file.
                string csvData = File.ReadAllText(csvPath);

                //Execute a loop over the rows.
                foreach (string row in csvData.Split('\n'))
                {
                    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(row))
                    {
                        csvDataTable.Rows.Add();
                        int i = 0;

                        //Execute a loop over the columns.
                        foreach (string cell in row.Split(','))
                        {
                            csvDataTable.Rows[csvDataTable.Rows.Count - 1][i] = cell;
                            i++;
                        }

                    }
                };

                GridView LoadedDrivers = (GridView)FindControl("LoadedDrivers");

                LoadedDrivers.DataSource = csvDataTable;
                LoadedDrivers.DataBind();
```

When I debug the code, it runs right up to the GridView statement where it throws the exception.  All of the variables populate in the locals pane.  I can see the data in csvDataTable.

There is a Site.Master page which very well could be an elephant.

The other elephant might be that I was instantiating the ImportCSV from the Controls page button handler.  I have changed that so the only thing being done on Controls is to click a button handler on Default and let it all exist in that space.  I'm still missing something.  The ImportCSV method works fine in several other elements of the project.  I haven't needed to use FindControl in other places.

Comment: How you going to referance a different page? I mean, why not then reference my open banking page while I visit your site? If I could play with and control other web pages, then what would stop me from reading your open web page on your gmail account? You can't really do what you ask. You could certainly have a timer on one page and on each timer event say check session(),and if say session of some value becomes valid, then you shove that session table into the grid, but you can't do cross browser control - it too large of a security hole and is in general not allowed.

Comment: Well, the button handler seems to find the method pretty easily.  Here is a question with several answers right here on Stackoverflow https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23996069/how-to-create-multiple-code-behind-file-for-aspx-page.  There are several articles about putting all of your business logic in a single page away from you gui handling code.  I am not talking about reaching out to your gmail or bank site.  I'm talking about two pages on the same site sharing information.  That seems like basic functionality.  Besides, the GridView is on the aspx page that the code page is calling from

Answer (score 0):

Unfortantly, you VERY much miss understand how a web server works.

Unlike desktop software?

The web system is called state-less. That means a copy of the web page ONLY exists client side. the web server does not keep in memory a copy of each users web page. In fact it does not even KEEP ONE copy in memory!!!

If 5 users all have the same web page open? There are NOT 5 instances of the web page class server side. In fact the .net class that represents the web page is NOT even existing, nor in memory.

If one user clicks a button on their web page? the ONE web server is just sitting there. If a post back occurs? Then the web server springs into action, load the page class, creates a NEW instance (and thus all variables in that page start from SCRATCH EACH TIME a post is made. The class instance is created, it now runs based on that page posted by the user. Rendering is done, and then the page is sent back to the client side and the CLASS COPY IN MEMEORY IS DISPOSED AND TOSSED OUT!!!

It does NOT exist anymore. So, if you try to reference a instance of that page class in another web browser from code behind, you find that the page class is NOT even memory, and all of its values (code variables) don't even exist!!!

So, the web server does not manage a page in memory for EACH user! The web server is just sitting there, waiting for ANY user to post back a page for processing. It is ONLY during that VERY short time when code behind runs does the instance of that class exists. Once the server has send the page back to the user, that class instance is tossed out and is gone!!!

So, you in fact have this setup:

[image]

Note how the page is sitting CLIENT side. On the server, THERE IS NOT a instance of that page class.

NOTE VERY careful here - the web page is ON CLIENT computer - it is NOT existing at all on the web server side.

You do not have this:
[image]

And you DO NOT HAVE this either:

[image]

Ok, You click the button. Now the so called round trip starts.

[image]

our web page is sent up to the server. You now have this:

[image]

So NOW your page is sitting on the server.

NOW a instance of the page class is created, and your code behind starts running.

Your code behind can modify controls (even visible), but the page is NOT interacting with the user - ONLY code can MODIFY the web page.

It is THEN sent back to the client side, and the server side class instance and code is TOSSED OUT - DOES NOT exist!!!

You now have this:

[image]

So, you can't do as you ask!! The server side instance of that other page is GONE!!!

And you would never know what user in question that class instance of that page belonged to if you could do this.

The web server is NOT like desktop software. The web server serves pages out to EVERYONE - the class instances of those pages don't exist until a post back occurs.

What you could do is have a timer on the first page. It could fire say every second, check some session value, and if your other page sets that session value, then the first page could load the grid. But you can't as a normal rule "garb" and paly with a instance of another page, since that instance DOES NOT exist!!!

(the page is sitting client side - NOT server side.

Comment: While I do appreciate your condescension as much and the next guy, and your pictures are all quite informative, I think you have failed to read the question.  The gridview is on Default.aspx.  The codebehind that this attempting to databind is in the Default.aspx.cs code file.  Now, if I were to look at all of your STRONGLY TYPED information then I would conclude that web development peaked with the <BLINK> tag.  I do appreciate the time you have invested though.

Comment: The target GridView does exist server side.  It exists in the aspx file.  The data that I want to populate it with does exist server side.  It is sitting in a datatable looking for a target.  In most cases, you simply databind.  That is an accepted practice.  It just doesn't seem to like the reference I am using.

Comment: Sure but you trying to do this from another page called control, and trying to referance the page class in default. As I stated, the page class does not exist, and in fact that page is just sitting on the users desktop. If you want the button and code to be moved over to the default page with gridview  - zero issues. but you CAN'T reference that page and gridview from another page (called control) -  the above explains why you can't do this. That page is client side - so no server side object from that "control" page running can see or use the page class "default".

Comment: I posted the question because I clearly do not understand the way to access this control.  That is what I am asking for help on.  The GridView is on Default.aspx.  The Bind statement is on Default.aspx.cs.  The button which is on Control.aspx and whose code-behind is on Control.aspx.cs has already triggered the method which reads in a csv file and parses it into a datatable in the Default.aspx.cs code page.  That much is working. What you seem to be saying is that you cannot update data in a Gridview because it is already in the client's browser.

Comment: Please, forget the fact that there is another webpage called Control.  It has already served it's purpose.  The Gridview I need to update is entirely within Default.  That should be doable.  Gridviews get updated all the time.  In fact, I have updated many of them myself.  There is significant communication between the server and the browser.  The structure of this site places the control elements in a different element.  This is not particularly different than having a nav bar that is a different html document, something that has existed since the early 90's.

Comment: Ok then either findcontrol is failing (and can't the control be referenced directly? (or is there a HUGE elephant in the room that this is a master/child page?). And we don't see the code for csvDataTable? So, the detail if a master/child is at play here, and that of csvDataTable is not shown. My spider sense guess is that find control not working, but either that or csvDataTable not working.

Comment: You can call a web method in a particular page (if marked as such and ALSO is static method), but without a page post-back, then all controls and values in that page can't be used - only if the actual page has been posted back can you do this. So a call to code in another page is much like a ajax call - the values and controls on the page in code behind don't exist, and can't be used. You can't use ViewState either - but you can use session().